# Giving a Java class name , I want to return its Parameter and Methods

Tags: java

Hey I want to implement the following functionality :

- the user provides a Java class name.
- this functionality will return all the method signatures and Parameters this class has.

What's the easiest way to do so?

NOTE : parsing a txt file is acceptable but I'm looking for a faster way.

Comment: "What's the easiest way to do so? " - reading the docs or by writing some code...

Answer (score 5):

Using reflection:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
Method[] methods = clazz.getMethods();
Field[] fields = clazz.getFields();
```

As others have suggested, read up on how to use [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/). Specifically, look at the methods [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) and [Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) provide in the Java API.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the tutorial for using Reflection. http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way?  Use the existing program javap